# Is Immutable.js v4.0.0-rc.12 ready for production?

Tags: immutable.js

I would like to use immutable.js, and see that [v4.0.0 is at rc.12](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable). That version string seems to indicate that v4.0.0 is not yet released. Is that because there is a problem with v4.0.0, and we should use 3.8.2, which is three years old? Is there a good fork that publishes v4.0.0 (or higher), so I can depend on it without raising questions about depending upon pre-release packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last autumn a new group of devs have started work to finish 4.0 at the [immutable-js-oss](https://github.com/immutable-js-oss) repo. It's not clear yet whether (or when) we can merge it back into the main repo (otherwise it will be released as a new package).

There are only a few things left to do for a final 4.0 release, 99% of the issues are already finished. If you are curious, have a look at the [issues of the 4.0 milestone](https://github.com/immutable-js-oss/immutable-js/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20milestone%3A4.0). The changes are mostly for compatibility with version 3.x and a few cases for handling very special data (e.g when passing nodejs objects to isolated sub-processes).

Our electron app uses RC12 since 2019, before it was on RC9 for a year. So far none of the 10'000 pilots using it crashed a plane, so I would say it works quite well.